# Why does <a-scene> trigger infinitely for ngDoCheck and trackBy?

Tags: javascript, angular, aframe

`<a-scene>` triggers `ngDoCheck` and `trackBy` when used in a template.

The use cases are simple:

**component**

```
ngDoCheck() { console.log('infinite spam'); }

trackByFn = (index: number, item: any): number => {
    console.log('infinite spam');
    return item['id'];
}
```

**template**

```
<a-scene>
    <!-- empty -->
</a-scene>
```

Please help me understand this

Answer (score 0):

ngDoCheck() is triggered by Angular's change detection to identify if ngOnChanges() method has to be run and if the DOM needs to be refreshed.

Also as a part of Angular's change detection cycle, the ngDoCheck() method is run for all user events like click, key press, navigation etc.

Comment: refer to this link for more details on why it is triggered: https://blog.angularindepth.com/if-you-think-ngdocheck-means-your-component-is-being-checked-read-this-article-36ce63a3f3e5

Comment: Why does it trigger when there are no under interactions? My assumption is that aframe is doing something in the background, so I am worried about the performance implications.